# -Who should be responsible to call runModalForWindow - the controller or the one initing the controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have a window (with its controller) that should block all other windows.
For that reason i want to show the window using [NSApp runModalForWindow..].

The question is who is the one responsible for calling this method:

1. the controller of the window (maybe i should override the showWindow function).
2. the object that created the controller. In that case, who should be responsible for calling stopModal?

Answer (score 1):

In my application, I have a class that implements the NSApplicationDelegate protocol - what you would get if you just started a simple project. That object has a view with controls and whatnot, and some of those controls can launch dialogs. So, in the case where I need to show an application-modal dialog as a response to a control, in the handler for that control (in my NSApplicationDelegate object) I call runModalForWindow. Say I have a class derived from NSWindowController called MyDialog, with an object MyDialog* theDialog. The call would look like:

```
NSResult result= [NSApp runModalForWindow:[theDialog window]];
```

It is the responsibility of the displayed object to call abortModal, stopModal or stopModalWithCode. So, inside MyDialog class I might have a handler for an "OK" button and a handler for a "Cancel" button:

```
-(void) onOk:(id)sender  
{  
  [NSApp stopModal];  // Returns NSRunStoppedResponse. 
  [[self window] performClose:self];  
}  

-(void) onCancel:(id)sender  
{  
  [NSApp abortModal];  // Returns NSRunAbortedResponse.  
  [[self window] performClose:self];  
}
```